# Splitting a string character by character in Powershell

Tags: powershell

What I want to do:  I have a string i.e "peter" and want to output the 1st character (p) in a variable.
Then the first 2 charachters (pe) etc. until the end of the string (peter).
At the end I would have 5 different variables.
Could anyone help me out how to do that in powershell ?

What I have tried is:

```
$Inputstring ="peter"
$CharArray =$InputString.ToCharArray()
$CharArray
```

but this gave me

```
p
e
t
e
r
```

This here looks good:

```
$TstString = "peter"

$CharArray = $TstString.ToCharArray()
$CharArray[0]
$CharArray[0] + $CharArray[1]
$CharArray[0] + $CharArray[1]+ $CharArray[2]
$CharArray[0] + $CharArray[1]+ $CharArray[2]+ $CharArray[3]
$CharArray[0] + $CharArray[1]+ $CharArray[2]+ $CharArray[3] + $CharArray[4]

p
pe
pet
pete
peter
```

I want to use that for checking ActiveDirectory for existing email address and if exist like p@dom.com; pe@dom.com ....

Comment: [1] what have you tried? what did not work as expected? [2] have you read the tour page for this site? pro'ly not, since your reputation is at `1` and you get rep points for reading that page. [3] what are you trying to achieve? this sounds like a sideways approach to another problem ... [*grin*]

Comment: Instead of creating 5 different variables, have you considered an **array** ?

Comment: For example, **1.** `$TstString = "peter"`, **2.** `$CharArray = $TstString.ToCharArray()`. Each would then be available separately as `$CharArray[0]` .. `$CharArray[4]`

Comment: Is the goal to check AD for every email address combination and output the results? Or is the goal to return the first unused email address starting with the one-character alias?

Comment: @AdminOfThings
The goal ist to return the first unused email address / UPN in AD starting with the one-character and assign this to a AD user. My problem is to find the unused addresses. Therefore I need a solution to check every returned email address with the email adresses in AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another way to get it done. [*grin*] what it does ...

- defines the string to work with
- loops thru the number of chars in the string
- uses the way that PoSh can index into a string by treating it as an array of chars to build a string
- joins the chars into one string
- sends that to a collection
- shows the content of that on screen

you can address each variant with `$Result[$Index]`, so there is no need for a hard-to-manage horde of variables. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
$InString = 'peter'

$Result = foreach ($Index in 0..($InString.Length - 1))
    {
    -join $InString[0..$Index]
    }

$Result
```

output ...

```
p
pe
pet
pete
peter
```

Comment: That´s cool !
how can I now check every variant in AD if it is ununsed or not ? Have not work it out. That would be the goal ;-)

Comment: @SKID - my usual idea is to generate the standard name, grab all matching names, and then - if there are matches - design a new name around those matches.

Comment: "how can I now check every variant in AD if it is ununsed or not ? "  look into Get-ADUser.  to get the command you will need to install Windows RSAT.

Comment: I would like to do that in a loop until the first unused address is found. But I did not find out how to to that...

Comment: @SKID - use `Get-ADUser` with a filter for the items that start with the pattern you have. then sort thru those until you find one that is not in use.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick way to produce all prefix strings for a given string:

```
PS> $prefix = ''; ([char[]] 'peter').ForEach({ ($prefix += $_) })
p
pe
pet
pete
peter
```

`$prefixes = ([char[] ...` would capture all prefixes as a string array for later processing; alternatively, you can perform the processing directly inside the `.ForEach()` block (remove the `(...)` around the `+=` assignment then, whose purpose is to also *output* the result of the assignment).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach for you

```
$str = 'peter'
$result = for ($len = 1; $len -le $str.Length; $len++) { $str.Substring(0, $len) }
```